# Starting with AR.js the documentation example does not work

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm starting with AR.js and having plenty of issues, so I tried re-starting again with the basics.

I do want to put a gltf file on top of a custom marker

I went to the documentation at (https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/#troubleshooting-feature-requests-community) to the image tracking example:

```
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>

<style>
  .arjs-loader {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .arjs-loader div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <!-- minimal loader shown until image descriptors are loaded -->
  <div class="arjs-loader">
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
  </div>
  <a-scene
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
    renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
    embedded
    arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled: false;"
  >
    <!-- we use cors proxy to avoid cross-origin problems -->
    <a-nft
      type="nft"
      url="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/trex-image/trex"
      smooth="true"
      smoothCount="10"
      smoothTolerance=".01"
      smoothThreshold="5"
    >
      <a-entity
        gltf-model="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/scene.gltf"
        scale="5 5 5"
        position="50 150 0"
      >
      </a-entity>
    </a-nft>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

I copied the code and put on a glitch project:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/discreet-horn-fog?path=index3.html%3A54%3A7

However, when I try to open it, the phone states in "Loading, please wait" forever.

I read somewhere that you have to use


To define your assets but not been able to make it work, I would appreciate any help I could get.

Thanks very much.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem opening the project on https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/

I tried multiple times to open the image tracking example, but it was always "Loading, please wait".

I noitced that if I opened the Codepen of the location based example it worked.

Then I opened both the Codepens of the two examples and also the image tracking one worked. I do not exactly why, but I was able to work on it.